# Angular 4 routes don't work from laravel public folder

Tags: laravel, angular, deployment, forge

I have a laravel json api being consumed by an angular 4 app,when it comes to deployment,I'm using forge with the contents of the dist folder in laravel's public folder,but I can't refresh any of my angular routes because laravel doesn't recognise them,they only work when navigating normally(clicking and so on) not when I enter them into the address bar of the browser or refreshing as I said.How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I have a same problem, so I figured out a way for over 3 hrs.
Here is my way.
1. Build angular 4 project first(ng build)
2. Copy all files except for 'index.html' in dist folder to public directory of laravel project.
3. replace content of resources/views/welcome.blade.php with angular4 index.html
4. add following codes to routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return View('welcome');
});
```

Please let me know if you have a problem still.

Comment: You're a life-saver dude,I was really stuck there,thank you so much :)